# How to get type of an object and then create array of objects with this type

Tags: c#, arrays, types

```
class baker: unit {}
class killer: unit{}

void Round(unit first, unit second, byte fA, byte sA)
{

    how to create array of "unit first" type objects?  

}
```

I pass baker or killer as a parameter and I want to clone this particular class in method, but I don't understand how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the simple approach :

```
if(first is baker)
{
// Create array of bakers
}
```

Or you can use Generics like so :

```
void Round<T>(T first, T second,...)
{
// Create the list of the type
new List<T>();
```

Or you can use :

```
Array.CreateInstance(first.GetType(), length);
```

In the worse case, you can use first.GetType() and use reflection to create an array.
But it's a bit more complicated

Comment: Thanks, last method is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: In the second approach, if you actually want an array (and not a `List<>`), say `new T[length]`.